# Remote git not accepting bash scripts

Tags: linux, git

My remote git used to work very well but when I added a `.sh` file in my project, my remote git started to reject the push without any particular reason (Push rejected: `Push master to XXX was rejected by remote`). My server is a CentOS 7 with ssh keys to connect with git.

Is pushing a bash script limited? If yes, what config should I change?

Comment: You're most likely out of space on remote.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40697415/git-push-rejected Checkout this link. Follow the first step