# How to update a file placed in my GitHUB REPOSITORY using command line

Tags: git, github

I recently pushed my first repository in the GitHub account from Linux Mint Terminal. It was quite straightforward. I can see my repository with all my files is there. I am also able to clone it successfully. All set.

Now I just want to update my README.md file or any other file and update this single file to GitHub account using the command line tool. Somehow, I am not able to do that. I dont want to login my github account and edit the file there, because this way my local and repository wont be same (unless I again pull it back to my local machine).

I tried this:

1. Edited the file.
2. git add .
3. git commit -m "adding a README File to the repository"
4. git push origin master

In the 4th step, I get the below error:

```
Username for 'https://github.com': xxx
Password for 'https://xxx@github.com': 
To https://github.com/xxx/MyTest.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (fetch first)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/xxx/MyTest.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

What am I doing wrong? There is any thing missing or the whole thing is wrong itself. I did not get a straight answer to this. Please suggest.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the steps you did take, only with the steps you didn't take.  You need to `git pull` to bring in the latest information from the remote `master` branch.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error message basically tells you what you need to do, which is to `git pull`.  Your problem is that since you have pulled, someone else has committed work to the remote `master` branch which is not part of your local `master` branch.  Try pulling to remedy this:

```
git pull origin master
```

You might get merge conflicts from this, in which case you would have to resolve them, then commit manually.  After this, you should be able to push with no issues:

```
git push origin master
```

Comment: Thank You. So for each change I make in any of my file, I will have to do this exercise.

Comment: Not necessarily.  If, after you have done a pull, commit, and push, you do more work _and_ no else pushes something to the remote `master` branch, then you might not have to `git pull` again.  You may think of `git pull` as the means by which you sync your local branch with everything happening to the remote branch.

Comment: I tried to make changes again and I had to follow the below steps:
    1. Edited the file.
    2. git add .
    3. git commit -m "3rd Commit"
    4. git pull origin master
    5. git push origin master

Answer (score 1):

Your question seems to match [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40697415/git-push-rejected)

git commit should be followed with a commit message and not a file (git commit -m "your message")